# Return an empty String with orElse()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to extract a value from an object list (`List<MyObj>`) to put it into a map.

**The condition is:** put the value or return an empty String. Something like that:

```
String score =
        collect.stream()
                .map(f -> f.getScore())
                .filter(filterScore("9096"))
                .orElse(() -> "");
```

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: *put the value or return an empty String* makes a little bit no sense...

Comment: Its to populate a map from a source.

Comment: so all you want is that if that value is present to populate a certain map? if so what is the key and the value? and what does *return an empty String* has to do with it?

Comment: What is the type of `MyObj.getScore()`?

Comment: I have a legacy application that is asking me to fill in a map that way, to later treat that data, with or without value.

Comment: *fill in a map that way* what way? you are only creating more confusion here

Comment: I know that it is not the objective of Optional and I know that the case is twisted . I just wanted to know if it was possible to do something similar.

Comment: are you doing this one purpose? :) *I just wanted to know if it was possible to do something similar* What similar? do you understand that probably no one here actually understood what you might even need? If you provide details and exactly what you mean, people are willing to help

Answer (score 1):

[`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) takes a value (a `String` in your case), not a `Supplier`. Additionally, you're missing a find term:

```
String score = 
    collect.stream()
           .map(f -> f.getScore())
           .filter(filterScore("9096"))
           .findFirst()
           .orElse("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a use `findFirst` to return an optional of the first element of the filtered list or an empty optional.

```
String score = collect.stream()
    .map(f -> f.getScore())
    .filter(filterScore("9096"))
.findFirst()
.orElse("");
```